# Order nested sets by another column (other than lft and rgt)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a comment section for a website (PHP/MySQL) where users can post comments
or reply to already posted ones. I've learned that this is a bit tricky to do because
RDBMS such as MySQL aren't really created for storing hierarchical data.
I've found 4 solutions to my problem (adjacency list, path enumeration, nested sets and closure table) 
of which I've chosen the nested sets (modified pre-order tree traversal).
I've managed to make this work for pulling and sorting the root comments and their replies
but I can't seem to find a way to sort the comments by points (other column) whithout breaking
the parent>child link.

Imagine a table like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id | comment | lft | rgt | pts|
+-------------------------------+
+-------------------------------+
| 1  | abc     | 1   | 8   | 3  |
+-------------------------------+
| 2  | 123     | 2   | 7   | 1  |
+-------------------------------+
| 3  | xyz     | 3   | 4   | 5  |
+-------------------------------+
| 4  | www     | 5   | 6   | 4  |
+-------------------------------+
| 5  | com     | 9   | 10  | 9  |
+-------------------------------+
```

If I order this by "lft ASC"
I get the standard chronological order (oldest to newest):

```
(1) abc
--(2) 123
----(3) xyz
----(4) www
(5) com
```

If orered by "rgt DESC"
I get the oposite i.e. new first (newest to oldest):

```
(5) com
(1) abc
--(2) 123
----(4) www
----(3) wxy
```

All of this works like a charm.
The problem is I can't seem to find a way to order the comments by points.
Eventually I would like to get an order like this:

```
(5) com (9 pts)
(1) abc (3 pts)
--(2) 123 (1 pts)
----(3) xyz (5 pts)
----(4) www (4 pts)
```

Is there any way to make the nested sets model behave like this.
If possile, the best way to do this is by using the right query, but if such a query doesn't 
exist ordering them with PHP is also acceptable (if it uses a reasonable ammout of resources).
And if this isn't reasonably possible using the nested sets model I would like to know
which model to use to produce all the ways to order the comments mentined above.

Comment: Why not just store the parent id of the comment the reply is for, then use PHP to build the nesting?

Comment: what defines a parent comment vs a child comment?  What do LFT and RGT specify?  You seem to have missed the most used method of storing this type of data... specifying the parent identifier in the child data, and using 0 for data without a parent.

Comment: @Fosco I think you're referring to the adjacency list model which has drawbacks when pulling the data from the database (it takes many SELECT statements to pull just one page of comments). See this link:
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Comment: Is this tree really correct? I thought that kind of structure required one unique root node (with `LFT = 1` and `RGT = (total_nodes*2)`. But you have two nodes on the "root level".

Comment: I think the nested set model is not a solution to your problem. It's elegant for hierarchical data but adding some weight to each node messes up everything. You may have to use some stored procedure to do part of the job there.

Comment: @user1200185 I don't think so... you can pull it all with one query.

Comment: I agree with others that maybe nested sets may not be the best solution here. The basic problem is, `LFT` and `RGT` encode both the position of each node in relation to its parents, and the position in relation to its siblings. So you'd have to actually move the nodes around (and reindex the tree) every time the score of a comment changes, to be able to simply `ORDER BY LFT` on your `SELECT`. Doesn't seem worthy terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this boils down to getting the depth and then ordering by depth and then points.

```
SELECT 
  c.*, 
  (COUNT(p.id) - 1) AS depth
FROM 
  comments AS c
  LEFT JOIN comments AS p ON c.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY depth, c.pts DESC
```

will produce:

```
id  comment lft     rgt     pts     depth
5   com     9       10      9       0
1   abc     1       8       3       0
2   123     2       7       1       1
3   xyz     3       4       5       2
4   www     5       6       4       2
```